# Can't get Mako engine in CherryPy to work

Tags: python, templates, cherrypy, mako

I need to set up a server using CherryPy and the Mako Template Engine, though I can't get the latter to work.

I started to integrate the code from [>>here<<](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/Mako) into my working CherryPy setup. Though in the end, I only see "Hello, ${username}!" as text instead of the inserted variable. Other information or examples I found via search or Google didn't solve that as well.

Since the code is quite long, I use pastebin to show it.

[server.py](http://pastebin.com/aYGVz9dh)

[app/application.py](http://pastebin.com/qTdrt9jz) << I put another version of the index module there, but I also tried it with on in the integration example linked above.

The content/index.html is this simple file:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello, ${username}!
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything I didn't setup right?

Comment: _"into my working CherryPy setup"_ --What is the working `CherryPy` setup that you mention?

Comment: Well, I can get my html files and python scripts to work on it. I use the CherryPy setup as a local server.

I uploaded and shared the files I think that are relevant.

Comment: In this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24578794/2072035) you can find CherryPy tools for Jinja2 and Cheetah. If you know the basics of Mako you should be able to change the template engine object and its calls accordingly.

Comment: So I finally realized that the "directories" doesn't seem to properly work. I just put my test files in the root folder of my project and it works for now.
Is there a way to insert the absolute path here instead? 

    "os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)"
this returns me the lib folder from my python installation.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggested you to do in the comment was in fact just a change of template engine instance. The rest is the same. Having a CherryPy tool to handle templating routine is very handy and gives you big flexibility at configuration.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os
import types

import cherrypy
import mako.lookup


path   = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}


class TemplateTool(cherrypy.Tool):

  _engine = None
  '''Mako lookup instance'''


  def __init__(self):
    viewPath     = os.path.join(path, 'view')
    self._engine = mako.lookup.TemplateLookup(directories = [viewPath])

    cherrypy.Tool.__init__(self, 'before_handler', self.render)

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if args and isinstance(args[0], (types.FunctionType, types.MethodType)):
      # @template
      args[0].exposed = True
      return cherrypy.Tool.__call__(self, **kwargs)(args[0])
    else:
      # @template()
      def wrap(f):
        f.exposed = True
        return cherrypy.Tool.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)(f)
      return wrap

  def render(self, name = None):
    cherrypy.request.config['template'] = name

    handler = cherrypy.serving.request.handler
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
      return self._render(handler, *args, **kwargs)
    cherrypy.serving.request.handler = wrap

  def _render(self, handler, *args, **kwargs):
    template = cherrypy.request.config['template']
    if not template:
      parts = []
      if hasattr(handler.callable, '__self__'):
        parts.append(handler.callable.__self__.__class__.__name__.lower())
      if hasattr(handler.callable, '__name__'):
        parts.append(handler.callable.__name__.lower())
      template = '/'.join(parts)

    data     = handler(*args, **kwargs) or {}
    renderer = self._engine.get_template('{0}.html'.format(template))

    return renderer.render(**data)


cherrypy.tools.template = TemplateTool()


class App:

  @cherrypy.tools.template
  def index(self):
    return {'foo': 'bar'}

  @cherrypy.tools.template(name = 'app/index')
  def manual(self):
    return {'foo': 'baz'}

  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  @cherrypy.expose
  def offtopic(self):
    '''So it is a general way to apply a format to your data'''
    return {'foo': 'quz'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Along the script create directory tree `view/app`, create `index.html` there with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Foo is: <em>${foo}</em></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notes about the tool:

- The decorator uses convention-over-configuration for template file name. It is `classname/methodname.html`. On occasion you may want to redefine the template with `name` keyword decorator argument.
- The decorator expose your method itself, no need to decorate with `cherrypy.expose`,
- You can use the tool as any other CherryPy tool in the configuration e.g. to make all  methods under `/app/some/path` to render data with corresponding templates.