# Mako rendering recipe from cherrypy docs does not work. What is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, cherrypy

I have copy-pasted the tool and plugin files from the Mako rendering recipe [pointed to](https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/cherrypy-recipes/src/tip/web/templating/) by the Cherrypy docs, and it simply does not work out of the box.

I have tried to track the problem and apparently, the response.finalize() method is called before the Mako tool is called, which modifies the response.body dictionary and gives a wrong input to the template. Why is this happening if the tool is configured with the 'before_finalize' option?

Another strange thing is that I need to set the response.status to 200 manually in the normal handler, as opposed to other [examples](https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/twiseless/webapp/).

I am using Python-3.4.3 and Cherrypy-3.7.0.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26618770/2072035).

Comment: @saaj I had already seen that post, and while I guess it works, I would appreciate if you could explain the reasons for the differences with respect to the much more clean and readable form in the recipe. I also see that you need to call the handler manually? How do you prevent it from running afterwards?

Comment: I explained the reason why I think splitting templating facility into a *tool* and a *plugin* and communicate them through the *bus* an overengineering in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24599189/2072035). But you're free to disagree with me. There's also approach to convention-over-configuration to not define template names by hand for every handler. It wraps the handler just like `HandlerWrapperTool` does, and you just apply the tool and it takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

After **@saaj**'s help and looking through the Cherrypy source code I have come to the conclusion that the recipe is no longer correct. My guess is that since it's a couple of years old, changes in newer versions might have rendered the recipe unusable. This is based on these facts:

- I have observed that the dictionary returned by the exposed handler gets converted into a list (in my basic test) so the renderer does not receive what it should.
- The json_out tool uses a different approach, which is actually very similar to what the HandlerWrapperTool does. Its hook point is 'before_handler' instead of 'before_finalize'.
- The response.status needs to be set in the exposed handler, as opposed to what happens [here](https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/twiseless/webapp/).

So in the end, I will use the snippet posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26618770/2072035), but I could also use something simpler, such as [this example](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.html#cherrypy._cptools.HandlerWrapperTool).

Comment: +1 for curiosity. In fact it's a Python 3 incompatibility where you can compare `int` and `NoneType` no longer. This line is buggy -- `if cherrypy.response.status > 399`, because normally, as far as I see, the status is `None`. Just prepend the condition with `cherrypy.response.status and`, if you like design of the recipe. Also, you may want to open an issue there for Sylvain to know he has a bug.

Comment: Good point, I didn't know it was a change in Python 3. I have already opened an issue (#1365) in the Bitbucket repo, pointing to this question. I have not been able to make the recipe work however, with the mount point 'before_finalize', due to some mechanism that transforms the dict (point 1). I hope someone can clarify whether there is some workaround or not. For the time being, I've integrated your snippet and works perfectly.